# Is there a consistent guidance on passing names into functions? Example with data.table

Tags: r

```
data(survey)
df <- survey
df$Sex <- as.character(df$Sex)

test <- function(x, y, z){
  a <- setDT(x)[, z := .N - 1L, by=y]
  setDF(a)
}

test2 <- function(x, y, z){
  a <- setDT(x)[, z := .N - 1L, by=substitute(y)]
  setDF(a)
}

test3 <- function(x, y, z){
  a <- setDT(x)[, z := .N - 1L, by=c(deparse(substitute(y))]
  setDF(a)
}

test(df, Sex, dup)
test2(df, Sex, dup)
test3(df, Sex, dup)
```

Ok, so test and test2 return a "no object" error, but test3 doesn't. I have no idea why. I don't understand why I can't just pass stuff in functions like it would be if I typed it outside a function, and I always end up just trying all the variations until one works. Is there a way to actually know this stuff? Like in this example, why doesn't test and test2 work?

Comment: The term to refer to is "non-standard evaluation" and you are not the first to be confused by it. To answer why there is an apparent inconsistency, you have to ask 'what if `x` contained a column `y`?' Should it group by `y` or by the value of `y`? More perversely, consider the function `quot <- function(y) "y"`. Naively, you could expect `quot(foo)` to return "foo" but of course it won't.

Comment: "Should it group by y or by the value of y? " can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

- `test` is not working because the data.table `by` is looking for the object `Sex` in the parent frame. the by argument accepts either a list or a vector. this is caused by the lazy evaluation of arguments. y is evaluated to Sex then Sex is not found causing the error to be thrown.
- As for `test2` it's basically the same issue, if you type `typeof(substitute(y))` it'll return "symbol" which is not a list but rather a promise object in `R` terms.
  A workaround would be to enclose the substitute call in `as.character()`.
- the last one works because you're turning the symbol created by substitute into a character.

#### Note

the column created would be named `z` as the `` ?data.table::`:=` ``  help shows that it's default behavior is to take a symbol. So you'll need to substitute it and deparse it like you did for y.

Comment: Isn't y a vector? It's a column of a data frame, and a column of a data frame is a vector, no?

Comment: if you were passing a string then it would be treated as such

Comment: but you're passing the an object named Sex

Comment: Ok. So couple followups. Is there a way to have R evaluate y as exactly what it would be in console? Like if I type Sex in console, it evaluates it correctly. Why can't I just make R evaluate it exactly as I would expect from typing it into console?

Comment: 2) If not, what would be another way to do this that doesn't rely on making it a quoted character string? The "by" argument accepts both strings and unquoted vector columns. My test3 does the string method, but is there a way to do the unquoted method?

Comment: I didn't get the first part.the way by works is by checking if the column exists then if not evaluate the value of `y` that's why the error is caused as it's not found.

Comment: If that's the case, then test should work. It is passing y, and y does exist. Sex exists, and if by checks if the column exists first, then it should find it. So the issue is it isn't interpreting Sex as Sex.

Comment: Essentially I'm wondering how to make R interpret things exactrly as inputted, I thought substitute() did that, but apparently not. –

Comment: I'll explain further test is not working because by looks for literal `y` then when the y column is not found it evaluates `y to Sex then to nothing` as Sex is not defined. that's why you need quoting to force by into reading Sex as Sex

Comment: they how come outside a function, it reads "Sex" as part of the column?

Comment: @Hutchins I fail to reproduce what you say. can you add it to the question with the output of sex and the column sex